# Unable to create image from bytea column of Postgres 9.3.1

Tags: java, postgresql-9.3

I have saved an image file in postgres db (9.3.1) in **bytea** column.
But the issue is I am getting **null** in **originalImage** with the following code.

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytesFromDB ) );
```

However, this code is working in postgres (8.4).
Why I am getting **null** in postgres (9.3.1)?

Comment: At a guess, because of the `bytea_output` default change from `escape` to `hex`, but it's hard to say without knowing your PgJDBC version etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Craig. I update jdbc driver from 9.1-901.jdbc4 to 9.3-1100-jdbc41. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old JDBC driver from before `bytea_output` support was added, plus a server where `escape` to `hex` by default, would explain this.

The driver doesn't know how to interpret `\xABCDEF` style output, and is trying to decode it as octal escape notation.